# Build error : The type or namespace name 'TweetSharp' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, build, package

I am developing a web application.

I have added tweetsharp library (latest package) from Nuget Package Manager.
It shows in references as well as provide intellisense, but when I try to run/build application it gives error that namespace could not be found.

My target framework is 4.0,
it also shows warning that newtonsoft.json is built against framework 4.5 but current target framework is 4.0.

I have tried to adding lower versions but it didn't help (I got the same error.)
I have also tried changing target framework to 4.5 but still get same error.

Comment: Maybe you should check that the path to the library is not longer than 255 chars. I had some similar build errors when there where paths longer than that, because the windows api does not accept paths longer than 255 chars. But Visual Studio was not able to display a meaningfull error message...

Comment: This classic error when target framework doesn't match. Build tweetsharp from source.

Comment: @user3096476 i checked by setting target framework to 4.5 but it is still giving that error

Comment: @ArjunVachhani Can you please post the error? Create a simple project in a new solution with the same settings as your original project and try referencing tweetsharp and build. Sometimes the path/projectname/assemblyname can be too long which will result in this error

Comment: @raeffs i had checked the path it just 91 character long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once faced the same problem. What I did was, i tried reinstalling the dll with the nuget package installer targeting the framework i am currently working on. It did not work.
I read somewhere that i should **first try to uninstall the current library package before reinstalling the downgraded framework based version of the library you are interested in.** 
Surprisingly it worked. Try it.

> I saw one of the comments regarding tweetstrap by user3096476

It might not be very clear. So i am also explaining it here:

Get the source code from the SVN (github). Change the target Framework to match your source code and build the **tweetstarp code**. Go to the **bin** folder and get the new DLL.
Add the reference to your current project. Now build your source code.
Hopefully it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean & build, this has gotten rid of many weird errors for me in the past.